# Appium : how to swipe left list view item

Tags: java, appium, ui-automation

I have an android app where my activity contains list view. I am working automation test case for swipe to delete list view item. I have written this code for fetching my list view:

```
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.id("com.xyz.email:id/conversation_list_view"));        
    list.get(0).click();
```

This code is supposed to click on first list view item but it is not working as expected.

I have written another code for swipe to delete list view item:

```
MobileElement emailCell = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.ListView/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.View");
    androidPhone.swipeOnElement("left", emailCell);
```

I have a function ready named "swipeOnElement" which swipe item from right to left.

```
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    double endX = 0;
    double endY = 0;

    int elementX = element.getCenter().x;
    int elementY = element.getCenter().y;
    int finalX;
    int finalY;

    switch (direction) {
        case "left":
            endX = size.width;
            break;

        case "right":
            endX = 0;
            break;

        case "up":
            endY = 0;
            break;

        case "down":
            endY = size.height;
            break;
    }
    if (direction == "left" | direction == "right") {
        finalX = (int) endX;
        finalY = elementY;
    } else {
        finalX = elementX;
        finalY = (int) endY;
    }
    System.out.println("startY=" + elementY);
    System.out.println("startX=" + elementX);
    System.out.println("endY=" + finalY);
    System.out.println("endX=" + finalX);

    new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(element)
            .waitAction(300)
            .moveTo(finalX, finalY)
            .release()
            .perform();
    delay(1000);
```

This function is fine. It is working perfectly. But when I tried it on list view item, it is not working as expected. I don't know why it behave like that. Any help please!!!

Comment: Sometimes issuing commands to the final pixel of an element can be buggy. I don't know that it'll solve your issue, but try setting your end values to 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @MikeCollins which end values you are talking about? You meant finalX and finalY?

Comment: Yes. Unlikely to fix our issue, but simple enough to try and something I could see potentially causing an issue.

Comment: Try using UiScrollable with MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator locator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found my solution:

There is a class available called TouchAction where you have to give parameters and called functions in the form of functional chaining.

```
new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(mobileElement)
            .waitAction(300)
            .moveTo(0,100)
            .release()
            .perform();
```

Here driver is an object of AppiumDriver and mobileElement is an object of MobileElement. moveTo function is what exactly doing the whole swiping things. It takes starting position and ending position for swiping.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
swipeLeft(MobileElement mobileElement) {
        LOGGER.info("Swiping Left ...");
        Dimension size = getWindowSize();
        int x1 = (int) (size.width * 0.01);
         new TouchAction(driver).press(mobileElement).waitAction(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).moveTo(x1,0).release().perform();
    }
```